# SharePoint 2013 Discussion Board Comments Approval Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

We have one discussion broad list with approval workflow on discussion. Discussion will be visible to users after approval. We want to implement approval workflow for comments also on discussion board. We have implement OOB workflow on comments as well and it is working fine as well but comments are visible before approval.

Can anyone have idea how to restrict the comments to be visible without approval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't default content approval created for this types of requirement?

Please try to turn on content approval and draft access restriction at `Versioning Settings` in discussion board settings.

Something like http://www.savtechsol.com/Education/BeckysBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122. Official doc is here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/825239, and keep in mind that discussion board is a simple list, and posts are list items

---

If you really want a *workflow* for this, this might help - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-workflow-to-manage-content-approval-for-a-library-A4D2CD8E-59CD-4FB1-A577-77DD106C0926. As soon as you enable content approval, it doesn't make a difference how approval status will be changed

Comment: I have enabled version for discussion board list. I have implemented OOB approval workflow for discussion content type and message content type. for discussion it is working fine. But for message content type workflow is working but the message / comments are visible to all whether they are approved, rejected or in pending status.

Comment: You are right, there are two content types: `Discussion` derived from 0x012002 and `Message` devired from 0x0107, they both are subject for Approval. Could you please verify that you have `Require content approval for submitted items` = `Yes` and `Who should see draft items in this list` = `Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)`? If your users are seeing items that are in "pending status", this indicates there might be some problems in configuration

Comment: Yes require content approval for submitted item is "Yes" on discussion board list. In list everyone can see all items i think this is the issue. Any workaround ?

Comment: And `Who should see draft items in this list` is `Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)`, right? Is there any chance all users you are testing under have a permission level that allows approving?

Comment: Yes only users who can approve items if selected. No i have checked for normal user permissions and users and contribute and read rights only.

Comment: That's really strange. Could you post a screenshot of that settings page please? You may want to create a separate question here in SP.SE regarding that issue, something like "regular users can see all item drafts in list despite Draft Item Security settings", and please include screenshots. Or maybe you can tweak the view? Like, **filter out** items where Approval Status == Draft

Comment: Dear i found the issue. Someone created a new permission level and assign that permission level to discussion list that's why this was happening. I deleted that permission level and it start working fine. Thanks for your answer it helps me find out the reason behind this issue.